# Redirection in Ingress nginx

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I would like to implement a redirection from the following address:
https://domain.name.com/abc/service.svc

to the new address:
https://domain.name.com/wcf/serviceNew/?wsdl

The challenge is that all users are still attempting to access the old address, and I am unable to change it. Is there a way to configure this redirection using Ingress?

I try in that way but without success:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world-ingress-static
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffering: "on"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 200m
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - domain.name.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: domain.name.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /wcf(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: wsrestservicewcf-service
            port:
              number: 8501
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: servicesserver-redirect
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location = https://domain.name.com/abc/service.svc {
        rewrite ^ https://domain.name.com/wcf/serviceNew/?wsdl permanent;
      }
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: domain.name.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: dummy-service  # Dummy service, won't be used
            port:
              number: 80
```

Thank you.

Comment: I believe this is feasible under Ingress-Nginx Controller. By using a rewrite feature. Based on the [documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) you can use the annotation [nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target](http://nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target).